# android new screen does not load correctly

Tags: android, android-intent, load, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Left to Right slide animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)

Can i make the screen that loads come from the left instead of the right.

```
Button bLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
bRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        startActivity(new Intent("Intent));
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean like an animation?

Comment: sort of its more like a presentation were one button goes left and the other one right but i have different classes am using but the right button and the left button make the screen load from the standard right i was hoping for a better user experience where the new activity loads from the direction they ask

Comment: What are you working for - you're setting `Button bLeft` But, setting listener for `bRight` is that right? And, is that right for syntax of `startActivity`

Comment: exactly the bRight and Bleft the activity works fine i was just hoping for a way to the new activity enter the screen from the left instead of the standard right

Comment: Try these answer - [Left to right animation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5151774/940096) and [Left to right](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6638566/940096)

Comment: am a lil lost that sounds for swiping correct? mine is just push buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

[Android Simple Activity Animation](http://technotzz.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/android-simple-activity-animation/)

[Android Simple Activity Animation Example 2](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/)

Comment: Button bRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
  bRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent("intent"));
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enterr,
                     R.anim.animation_leavel);

    finish();
    

   }
   });

Comment: it gives me an error on the overridependingtransition

Comment: it doesnt do it and i had to put this on the code private void overridePendingTransition(int animationEnterl,
     int animationLeaver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Comment: am a lil new to the android programing whats stacktrace?

Comment: its really long can you check to see if this looks right to you?Button bLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
  bLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent("intent"));
    finish();
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enterl,
                     R.anim.animation_leaver);
    

   }

   private void overridePendingTransition(int animationEnterl,
     int animationLeaver) {
    
    
   }

Comment: there is no red in the log :(

Comment: yes am runing it in a galaxy s 2 and a panteck burt but the transition doesnt happen

Comment: please make sure that you have set Settings>Display>Animation to Display all animations in your handset

Comment: both of them have all animations i just checked :(

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087366/displaying-activity-with-custom-animation)

Comment: sounds like a different approach but what happen is i have many activities linked to one xml file thats y i wanted to go the java route

Comment: [this](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/) example also have good explanation

Comment: thank you both ill look into it haha i have to take some advil i got a headache from thinking i wish the world knew how hard programing is haha that way a tiny bug wouldnt be that big deanl :)

Comment: I havent founded yet but as soon as i do ill accept it, StackOverFlow is a great site

Comment: ive been looking but nothing works, can someone maybe check my code on the top to see if am missing anything for the transition?

Comment: finally found somenthing that works guys here is the linkhttp://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/splash-fade-activity-animations-overridependingtransition-t9464.html